# Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException with TypedFactoryFacility

Tags: castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility, windsor-facilities

I am having some problem resolving ITcpServer when using TypedFactoryFacility. It seems that Windsor does not find a suitable component to be returned from factory for the interface. What is specific to my case is that the interface ITcpServer is non-generic while classes implementing it are both generic.

The following code throws when run:

> Unhandled Exception: Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: No
>   component for supporting the service
>   ConsoleApplication1.StandardTcpServer`1 was found    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type
>   service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)    at
>   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryComponentResolver.Resolve(IKernelInternal
>   kernel, IReleasePolicy scope)    at
>   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Resolve(IInvocation
>   invocation)    at
>   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation
>   invocation)    at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>   at Castle.Proxies.ITcpServerFactoryProxy.Create[T](String serverType,
>   T something)

The code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new MyWindsorInstaller());

        var f = container.Resolve<ITcpServerFactory>();
        var tcpServer = f.Create("standard", "something");
        tcpServer.Start();
    }
}

 public class MyWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ITcpServer>().ImplementedBy(typeof(LibUvTcpServer<>)),
            Component.For<ITcpServer>().ImplementedBy(typeof(StandardTcpServer<>)),
            Component.For<ITcpServerFactory>().AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith(new TcpServerComponentSelector()))
            );
    }
}

public class TcpServerComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override Type GetComponentType(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        var serverType = (string)arguments.First();
        return serverType == "standard" ? typeof (StandardTcpServer<>) : typeof(LibUvTcpServer<>);
    }
}

public interface ITcpServerFactory
{
    ITcpServer Create<T>(string serverType, T something);
}

public class StandardTcpServer<T> : ITcpServer
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
    }
}

public class LibUvTcpServer<T> : ITcpServer
{
    private readonly T something;

    public LibUvTcpServer(T something)
    {
        this.something = something;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
    }
}

public interface ITcpServer
{
    void Start();
}
```

Any help in solving the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following:

```
protected override Type GetComponentType(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
{
    var serverType = (string)arguments.First();
    if (serverType == "standard") 
    {
        return typeof(StandardTcpServer<>).MakeGenericType(arguments[1].GetType());
    }
    else
    {
        return typeof(LibUvTcpServer<>).MakeGenericType(arguments[1].GetType());
    }
}
```

and the registration:

```
Component.For<ITcpServer>().Forward(typeof(LibUvTcpServer<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(LibUvTcpServer<>)),
Component.For<ITcpServer>().Forward(typeof(StandardTcpServer<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(StandardTcpServer<>)),
```

or if you only need to resolve through the factory:

```
Component.For(typeof(LibUvTcpServer<>)),
Component.For(typeof(StandardTcpServer<>)),
```

Good luck,

Marwijn.